# Paperclip throws NoHandlerError with base64 photo

Tags: ios, ruby-on-rails, api, paperclip

When upgrading from paperclip 2 to paperclip 3 my image upload API brakes. This code used to work :

```
def decode_cover_image_data(cover_image_data)
    data = StringIO.new(Base64.decode64(cover_image_data))
    data.class.class_eval { attr_accessor :original_filename, :content_type }
    data.original_filename = "cover.png"
    data.content_type = "image/png"

    self.photo = data
end
```

It now raises a NoHandleError exception :

> "Paperclip::AdapterRegistry::NoHandlerError (No handler found for
>   "/9j/4AAQD/4Q[...]wooooGf/9k="

Did anybody encounter this problem ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found where the problem was coming from, it's quite stupid...

In my controller update method i had something like :

```
  def update
    ...
    if p[:photo]
      @user_ipad.decode_cover_image_data(p[:photo])
    end

    unless @user_ipad.update_attributes(p)
      render :json => {:errors => @user_ipad.errors}
    end
  end
```

The issue is that i'm setting the user photo 2 times :

- Once in  @user_ipad.decode_cover_image_data(p[:photo])
- Once in @user_ipad.update_attributes(p)

The crash occured when saving the base64 string (still in the parameters) with update_attributes. Actually what surprise me is that this piece of code works with Paperclip 2.4.5 ...

After upgrading to Paperclip 3.3.1 i solved my problem by replacing my update method with this :

```
  def update
    ...
    if p[:photo]
      p[:photo] = @user_ipad.decode_cover_image_data(p[:photo])
    end

    unless @user_ipad.update_attributes(p)
      render :json => {:errors => @user_ipad.errors}
    end
  end
```